# Computer does not display output to the screen

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, dvi, cable

I am writing this post with connection to the new computer which I had bought recently.

When I have plugged everything and turned on computer, then it is looks like running (light + DVD ROM are working), however my monitor doesn't detect anything. Then I have tried to plug into TV with HDMI without success as well.

Monitor is just black and some rectangle is going around monitor with the text "Check signal cable", so same situation like no computer is plugged in.

I am plugging it like this:

Computer with graphic card Geforce GTX 950 (DVI slot) -> adapter VGA-DVI -> cable VGA -> monitor Samsung Sync Master 933

I do not think this will be important, but the previous problem with computer was problem with cooling - computer terminated frequently on higher capabilities, but this is fixed and better fan system is installed.

I had the monitor from my previous PC. Because of budget I preferred to buy better hardware and stay with this monitor, which is not so bad. 
Do you believe that my PC is too weak for GTX 950?  Because my brother has the same set - same monitor and same hardware and his computer is working properly.

Anyone have some hint?

Comment: Is there a reason you have a Geforce GTX 950 but not a monitor that can use a digital resolution? Edit: That sounded rude. I work in an IT shop and we can't get new monitors due to budget and I wondered if it was the same for you or if this is a personal rig.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.